# How to expand a cropped image into a box?

Tags: css

I am given a JPEG image which needs to be cropped using CSS and then expanded to fit a `1200px x 1000px` box.

Here is what I have so far:

```css
#top-image {
    display: block;
    clip-path: inset(0px 103px 45px 105px);
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/750x500" id="top-image">
```

The `clip-path` property crops the original image which is `750px x 500px`. When I set width and height to values mentioned in the above snippet, two problems occur:

- The pixel values used in `clip-path` are based on the new `1200 x 1000` box, not for the original image.
- The original (uncrossed) image (including cropped parts) is expanded to the box. However, I would like to expand the cropped image to fill the box.

  What is the best way of doing this using pure CSS?

**Update 1:**
I can solve the first issues by using percentages instead of pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use background for this and adjust `background-size`/`background-position`:

```css
#top-image {
    display: block;
    /*clip-path: inset(0px 103px 45px 105px);*/
    width: 1200px;
    height: 1000px;
    background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/1200/1000?image=0);
    
    background-size:
      calc(100% + 103px + 105px) /*100% of the width + the cropped part*/ 
      calc(100% + 45px); /*100% of the height + the cropped part*/
    background-position:
      -103px /*we shift to the left to crop the 103px*/
      0; /*we keep at the top and the bottom will be cropped*/
}
```

```html
<div id="top-image"></div>
```

The above one will crop pixel based on the container. In case you need to crop based on the image size you do this:

```css
#top-image {
    display: block;
    /*clip-path: inset(0px 103px 45px 105px);*/
    width: 1200px;
    height: 1000px;
    background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/750/500?image=1069);
    
    background-size:
      calc(750px*(1200/(750 - 103 - 105)))  
      calc(500px*(1000/(500 - 45))); 
    background-position:
      calc(-103px*(1200/(750 - 103 - 105))) 
      0; 
}
```

```html
<div id="top-image"></div>
```

Your image has a height of `500px` and you want to crop `45px` thus we will have `455px` that need to cover `1000px` so we need to multiply by `1000/455`. Same logic with the width. For the position we need to shift by the `103px` crop considering the same multiplication.

---

We can also write this differently.

I will use the below image (`300x150`) that I will crop `100px` from the left, `60px` from the right, `10px` from the top and `45px` from the bottom. Then it will cover a container with a dimension of `400x200`. We should only see the yellow part.

[image]

```css
.image {
    display: block;
    margin:5px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xde45.png);
    
    background-size:
      calc(300px*(400/(300 - 100 - 60))) 
      calc(150px*(200/(150 - 10  - 45))); 
    background-position:
      calc(-100px*(400/(300 - 100 - 60))) 
      calc(-10px *(200/(150 - 10  - 45)));
}
.alt {
    background-size:
      calc(100% + (100 + 60)*(400px/(300 - 100 - 60))) 
      calc(100% + (45 + 10) *(200px/(150 - 10 -  45))); 
    background-position:
      calc(-100*(400px/(300 - 100 - 60))) 
      calc(-10 *(200px/(150 - 10  - 45)));
}
.alt2 {
  --c-left:100;  /*crop left*/
  --c-right:60;  /*crop right*/
  --c-bottom:45; /*crop bottom*/
  --c-top:10;    /*crop top*/
  --c-x:calc(var(--c-right) + var(--c-left));
  --c-y:calc(var(--c-top) + var(--c-bottom));
  background-size:
      calc(100% + var(--c-x)*(100%/(300 - var(--c-x)))) 
      calc(100% + var(--c-y)*(100%/(150 - var(--c-y)))); 
    background-position:
      calc(-1*var(--c-left)*(400px/(300 - var(--c-x)))) 
      calc(-1*var(--c-top) *(200px/(150 - var(--c-y)))) ;
}
```

```html
<div class="image"></div>
<div class="image alt"></div>
<div class="image alt2"></div>
```

We can take the last syntax and consider more variable to have some more dynamic and responsive:

```css
.image {
    display: block;
    margin:5px;
    width: var(--w,400px);
    height: var(--h,200px);
    background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xde45.png);
    --c-left:100;  /*crop left*/
    --c-right:60;  /*crop right*/
    --c-bottom:45; /*crop bottom*/
    --c-top:10;    /*crop top*/
    
    --c-x:calc(var(--c-right) + var(--c-left));
    --c-y:calc(var(--c-top) + var(--c-bottom));
    background-size:
      calc(100% + var(--c-x)*(100%/(300 - var(--c-x)))) 
      calc(100% + var(--c-y)*(100%/(150 - var(--c-y)))); 
    background-position:
      calc(-1*var(--c-left)*(var(--w,400px)/(300 - var(--c-x)))) 
      calc(-1*var(--c-top) *(var(--h,200px)/(150 - var(--c-y)))) ;
}
```

```html
<div class="image"></div>
<div class="image" style="--w:200px;--h:100px;"></div>
<div class="image" style="--w:150px;--h:150px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for providing this solution. The solution presented here seems to have everything I'm looking for except the fact that pixel values are defined based on original image size instead of the expanded image size. How should I handle that?

Comment: In other words, when I use the solution as is, the cropping points are not the ones I'm looking for.

Comment: Can this be implemented using `vh` and `vw` instead of pixels?

Comment: The reason I am asking is that solutions which use `px` are not compatible with `background-attachment: fixed`. It causes the image size to change even though it is defined in the `.image` class.

Comment: Another problem with the solution that is based on `px` is that it does not work the same across different displays with various resolutions.

Comment: @Mahdi vh and vw won't work and it's the same when using `fixed`. It become a complete new problem in this case.vh and vw are browser unit that are defined based on the screen size so we cannot use them in order to define the cropped image. I think it would be insane trying to do this but I recommend you asking a new question detailing all this and probably we may find some workaround to achieve what you want