# How to avoid corruption of image size due to fixing background attachment?

Tags: css

I have a `750px x 500px` image and need to fit it in a `1200px x 1000px` box. The image has to be cropped from different sides and only a subset is scaled to the large box.

I have used the following code snippet to implement both crop and resize operations. The solution is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54272230) question.

```css
#top-image {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/750x500);
    background-size: 
        calc(750px * (1200 / (750 - 103 - 105))) 
        calc(500px * (1000 / (500 - 47)));
    background-position: 
        calc(-105px * (1200 / (750 - 103 - 105)))  
        0px;
    filter: brightness(85%);
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

The next step is to apply a simple Parallax effect to this background image by adding the following line to `#top-image`:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

However, adding the aforementioned line leads to corruption in the cropped and resized image such that the image is different from the one without the Parallax effect.

How should I crop and resize to get the same picture regardless of whether the aforementioned line is added or not?

Comment: The snippet doesn't show a background image nor did you attach an image showing the problem... however could it be [related to this](https://www.fourkitchens.com/blog/article/fix-scrolling-performance-css-will-change-property/)?

Comment: Your snippet is missing html, edit that in.