# How do I clip a Background image and move it with an animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html2canvas

I am working on an animation for part of my website, and I wanted to be able to clip or capture a porting of the background image and move it with an animation. The only similar thing I have found is from https://squarespace.com. I figured a good way to learn was to mimic their animation, but I don't know how to clip the background. Or do I need to lay an image over top and clip that?
Any help would be great!

I have tried `background-clip:`, but I can't seem to get the right results.

Here is a Codepen of some progress I have made.

Click [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PVKwYy)

> New thought!

What if I used something like [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) to capture a portion of the background image. Would this be possible? Is anyone familiar?

Comment: No codepen link attached

Comment: @brooksrelyt Wow, not sure how I missed that. Thank you so much, it is fixed now.

Comment: there is no animation in the codepen

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes, I am not sure how to capture the part of the background contained in the div. If I could though animation should be easy. See Squarespace's Website to understand what I mean.

Comment: here is what you need I guess : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54272274/8620333 it will allow you to crop a part of the image like you want, simply follow the calculation well

Answer (score 1):

Just apply **[clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)** to any element. You can then modify the clip path (a simple polygon in my example) via CSS or JavaScript. Here an example with CSS for simplicity's sake:

```css
body {
margin: 0;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  background: #eee;
  height: 100vh;
}

.octagon {
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(30% 0%, 70% 0%, 100% 30%, 100% 70%, 70% 100%, 30% 100%, 0% 70%, 0% 30%);
clip-path: polygon(30% 0%, 70% 0%, 100% 30%, 100% 70%, 70% 100%, 30% 100%, 0% 70%, 0% 30%);
}

.textbox {
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
word-break: break-all;
overflow: hidden;
background: #FFF;
}

.background  {
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
background: #000 url(http://lorempixel.com/300/300/sports/7) no-repeat center center scroll;
background-size: cover;
color: #FFF;
}

.animated {
  animation: animation_polygon 6000ms alternate infinite ease;
}


@keyframes animation_polygon {

  25% {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(45% 33%, 70% 0%, 73% 41%, 100% 70%, 62% 79%, 30% 100%, 36% 60%, 0% 30%);
    clip-path: polygon(45% 33%, 70% 0%, 73% 41%, 100% 70%, 62% 79%, 30% 100%, 36% 60%, 0% 30%);
  }

  50% {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(19% 6%, 57% 28%, 93% 17%, 70% 49%, 81% 93%, 45% 54%, 3% 69%, 35% 39%);
    clip-path: polygon(19% 6%, 57% 28%, 93% 17%, 70% 49%, 81% 93%, 45% 54%, 3% 69%, 35% 39%);
  }
  
  75% {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(35% 36%, 60% 2%, 60% 35%, 95% 67%, 64% 65%, 13% 93%, 30% 59%, 4% 38%);
    clip-path: polygon(35% 36%, 60% 2%, 60% 35%, 95% 67%, 64% 65%, 13% 93%, 30% 59%, 4% 38%);
  }

}
```

```html
<main>

<img class="octagon animated" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/sports/2">

<div class="octagon animated background">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
</div>

<div class="octagon textbox">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
</div>

<img class="octagon animated" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/sports/5">

</main>
```